# undefined response from json data

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-routing

setting up for the *client* to *register*.
this is the function that registers a client.

```
  registerAsClient(){
  this.loading =this.loadingCtrl.create({
   content:"Setting up Account"
  });
this.loading.present();
this.buildClientData();
console.log(this.clientData);
this.auth.store('clients', this.clientData).subscribe((response)=>{

  this.clients = response.json();
```

this is to show the response from the server after registration to console.

```
  console.log("Client ID : " + this.clients['clientId']);
  console.log("Savings Account ID : " + this.clients['savingsAccountId']);

  localStorage.setItem('clientID', this.clients['clientId']);
  localStorage.setItem('officeID', this.clients['officeId']);
  localStorage.setItem('savingsAccountID', this.clients['savingsAccountId']);

  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.loading.dismissAll();
    this.toastrCtrl.messenger('Successfully Registered'); 
    localStorage.setItem('registered', 'true');
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
       },5000)
  },error=>{
    if(error.status === 403){
      this.loading.dismissAll();
      this.toastrCtrl.messenger("Phone number already exists. Please use another");
    }else
     this.loading.dismissAll();
     this.toastrCtrl.messenger('Service unavailable. Please try again later'); 
     console.log(error);
      // alert(JSON.stringify("Error is  :" + error));
})
}
```

this is the response from the console registering 
i am able to get the client id but the savings account id is showing as undefined.

```
Client ID : 104 
Savings Account ID : undefined
```

total `json` response when testing with the endpoints.

```
{
"id": 89,
"accountNo": "000000089",
 "status": {
"id": 300,
"code": "clientStatusType.active",
"value": "Active"
 },
 "subStatus": {
"active": false,
"mandatory": false
 },
"active": true,
"activationDate": [
  2018,
  8,
 13
 ],
 "firstname": "Albertina",
 "lastname": "Ben-Patterson",
 "displayName": "Albertina Ben-Patterson",
 "mobileNo": "0201234598",
 "gender": {
  "active": false,
  "mandatory": false
 },
 "clientType": {
 "active": false,
 "mandatory": false
  },
  "clientClassification": {
"active": false,
"mandatory": false
 },
"isStaff": false,
 "officeId": 10,
 "officeName": "Greater Accra Region",
 "timeline": {
 "submittedOnDate": [
  2018,
  8,
  13
 ],
"submittedByUsername": "admin",
"submittedByFirstname": "App",
"submittedByLastname": "Administrator",
"activatedOnDate": [
  2018,
  8,
  13
],
"activatedByUsername": "admin",
"activatedByFirstname": "App",
"activatedByLastname": "Administrator"
},
"savingsAccountId": 8,
"groups": [],
"clientNonPersonDetails": {
 "constitution": {
  "active": false,
  "mandatory": false
 },
  "mainBusinessLine": {
  "active": false,
  "mandatory": false
 }
}
}
```

thanks.

Comment: savingsAccountID might be set twice, first with data and second with undefined. Are there multiple calls?

Comment: @muasif80 no please.

Comment: Put this `console.log("Client ID : ", this.clients);` after `this.clients = response.json();` see what does it show you?

Comment: Do you have a defined class or interface for client type? If yes please share it.

Comment: @muasif80 https://jsbin.com/somipayira/edit?html,css,js,console you can check the code here

Comment: @muasif80 console.log("Client ID : ", this.clients); still undefined

Comment: You need to check your network tab to see what response is coming back. Can you take screenshot of it and paste here. Your provided link is not of much help as i cant run it.